# Writing inline css in React.js

Tags: reactjs

How to write inline CSS in react.js

```
<div className="p-3" style={{backgroundImage: linear-gradient(to right top,#FB0712,#124FEB)}}>
```

getting an error(Error: error: Expected ',', got 'right') with the above code

Comment: You need to wrap `linear-gradient(to right top,#FB0712,#124FEB)` with quotes to make it a valid string: `"linear-gradient(to right top,#FB0712,#124FEB)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had used something like below and it worked for me.

```
<div style={{backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(to right top,#FB0712,#124FEB)`, height: '20px', width: '20px'}}/>
```